# Facebook like box for a group

Tags: facebook

Could any one please help me in adding a Facebook like for a group?

I have tried to add the group url in the Facebook page URL:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

But I am getting the following error:

> Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.

Comment: Although this site is backed by an SQL-based RMDB, you **need not** use ALL CAPS in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can like Pages and Website-URLs, but you cannot like Groups. It´s that simple. You may only try with a public group, but i don´t think it works either. I just tried and at least there is no error if you use a public group, you can even click the Like button but it does not show up on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous responder , you cannot add a like box for a group because they don't collect likes, they collect members.